Middleware for fetching the user from database for each request
I have a (SQLAlchemy) User model as follows:
class User(BaseModel):
    id: uuid: Mapped[UUID] = mapped_column(UUID, ...)

I need to check if the user exists in DB for every request. I know I should define a dependency for it, but I have more than 100 tiny and big endpoints. So, it's not a good approach to add a dependency in all of them one by one.
So, I need to define two middlewares:

SessionMiddleware: Generates a SQLAlchemy session for each request

AuthenticationMiddleware: Fetches the user from the DB using the session from the previous middleware (SessionMiddleware). 


I created the two above middlewares as follows:
class SessionMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        if scope["type"] == "http":
            # Create a new database session
            request = Request(scope, receive, send)
            request.state.db_session = next(get_db())
            try:
                # Process the request
                await self.app(scope, receive, send)
            finally:
                # Ensure the session is closed
                if hasattr(request.state.db_session, "close"):
                    request.state.db_session.close()
        else:
            await self.app(scope, receive, send)


class AuthenticationMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def __call__(self, scope, receive, send):
        db_session = request.state.db_session
        try:
            request.state.user = User.query(db_session).find_one(name=client_name)
            await self.app(scope, receive, send)
        except NotFoundError:
            raise JSONResponse(detail=User.object_not_found_error())
 

When I work with Swagger, it works fine and returns the response or raises the error in the right situation.
But the issue is when I want to write tests by using Pytest. In order to isolate tests, I want to generate a database session at the beginning of each unit test, pass it to the endpoint, and then roll back it at the end of each unit test. On the other hand, I need the same database session in the test function and also in the endpoint.
So, I have to override the SessionMiddleware. I tried different ways but I couldn't find the solution.
In summary, I need to access the same database session in the test functions and in the endpoints.

First of all, for your case, you may want to use global dependencies which are covered in fastapi's documentations (link).
About testing, you may wanna go through this issue in sqlalchemy's repo or If you just want an example:
from typing import AsyncGenerator, Generator

import pytest
from httpx import ASGITransport, AsyncClient
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event, text
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import async_sessionmaker, create_async_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, SessionTransaction

from api.config import settings
from api.database.registry import *  # noqa: F403
from api.database.setup import (
    async_database_url_scheme,
    get_session,
    sync_database_url_scheme,
)
from api.main import app

pass  # Trick to load `BaseDatabaseModel` the last, since all database models must be imported before base model.
from api.database.models import BaseDatabaseModel  # noqa: E402


@pytest.fixture
def anyio_backend() -> str:
    return "asyncio"


@pytest.fixture
async def ac() -> AsyncGenerator:
    transport = ASGITransport(app=app, raise_app_exceptions=False)
    async with AsyncClient(transport=transport, base_url="https://test") as c:
        yield c


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def setup_db() -> Generator:
    engine = create_engine(
        sync_database_url_scheme.format(
            settings.DATABASE_USERNAME,
            settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
            settings.DATABASE_HOST,
            settings.DATABASE_PORT,
            "",
        )
    )
    conn = engine.connect()
    # Terminate transaction
    conn.execute(text("commit"))
    try:
        conn.execute(text("drop database test"))
    except SQLAlchemyError:
        pass
    finally:
        conn.close()

    conn = engine.connect()
    # Terminate transaction
    conn.execute(text("commit"))
    conn.execute(text("create database test"))
    conn.close()

    yield

    conn = engine.connect()
    # Terminate transaction
    conn.execute(text("commit"))
    try:
        conn.execute(text("drop database test"))
    except SQLAlchemyError:
        pass
    conn.close()
    engine.dispose()


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def setup_test_db(setup_db: Generator) -> Generator:
    engine = create_engine(
        sync_database_url_scheme.format(
            settings.DATABASE_USERNAME,
            settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
            settings.DATABASE_HOST,
            settings.DATABASE_PORT,
            "test",
        )
    )

    with engine.begin():
        BaseDatabaseModel.metadata.drop_all(engine)
        BaseDatabaseModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
        yield
        BaseDatabaseModel.metadata.drop_all(engine)

    engine.dispose()


@pytest.fixture
async def session() -> AsyncGenerator:
    # https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5811#issuecomment-756269881
    async_engine = create_async_engine(
        async_database_url_scheme.format(
            settings.DATABASE_USERNAME,
            settings.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
            settings.DATABASE_HOST,
            settings.DATABASE_PORT,
            "test",
        )
    )
    async with async_engine.connect() as conn:
        await conn.begin()
        await conn.begin_nested()
        AsyncSessionLocal = async_sessionmaker(
            autocommit=False,
            autoflush=False,
            expire_on_commit=False,
            bind=conn,
            future=True,
        )

        async_session = AsyncSessionLocal()

        @event.listens_for(async_session.sync_session, "after_transaction_end")
        def end_savepoint(session: Session, transaction: SessionTransaction) -> None:
            if conn.closed:
                return
            if not conn.in_nested_transaction():
                if conn.sync_connection:
                    conn.sync_connection.begin_nested()

        def test_get_session() -> Generator:
            try:
                yield AsyncSessionLocal
            except SQLAlchemyError:
                pass

        app.dependency_overrides[get_session] = test_get_session

        yield async_session
        await async_session.close()
        await conn.rollback()

    await async_engine.dispose()

Let me explain the piece of code that I have written:

First of all, we need to import all models before BaseMetadata. This is what from api.database.registry import * does; in this file I have imported all models.
ac is a asynchronous httpx client.
Using setup_db fixture, in each test session we make sure we create a fresh testing database and drop it afterwards. setup_test_db creates all tables, enums, constraints, etc. based on given metadata class and drops all of them after testing.
Last and the most important part is session fixture. This fixture joins all transactions in a single test and rollbacks all of them. This way you don't need to worry if have even committed some changes to database. In addition to what I said, also we get the original database session dependency and change it to what we have created using dependency overrides.

If you need more detail about what I have done, please let me know.
